# Delete one marker in googlemap api v3

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

When I search for a location with the zip code, I center the googlemap with with the zip code and I add a marker. When I do a new search I would delete the old marker.

```
     $('body').on('blur', '#CodePostalA', function(){

        var zipcode = $('#CodePostalA').val();
        var $this = $(this);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

            geocoder.geocode({'address': zipcode}, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    map.setZoom(20);

                }

                if ($('#adresse').length > 0) {
                    newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(
                            'images/marker-new.png',
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            new google.maps.Size(36, 36)
                        ),
                        draggable: true,

                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    });



                    google.maps.event.addListener(newMarker, "mouseup", function(event) {
                        var latitude = this.position.lat();
                        var longitude = this.position.lng();


                        geocoder.geocode({'location': this.position}, function(results, status) {
                            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                if (results[1]) {
                                    $('#adresse').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                } else {
                                    console.log('Aucun résulat trouvé');
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.log('Echec géolocation: ' + status);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                }




            });



    });



    addMarkers(props, map);
}, 300);
```

Comment: newMarker.setMap(null); try this before creating new marker

Comment: ok i understand but when i add newMarker.setMap before newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({}),  i have error in my console => Uncaught TypeError: newMarker.setMap is not a function

Comment: duplicate of [Geocoding with Google Maps API - updating existing marker rather than adding another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628994/geocoding-with-google-maps-api-updating-existing-marker-rather-than-adding-ano)

Comment: Why would you call setMap before creating the marker?

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of your marker with a variable, and when it is time to delete it, remove it from the map with `marker.setMap(null)`.

Once all references have been removed the old marker object will be garbage collected behind the scenes.

You could also consider reusing the marker object rather than making a new one every time.